# Is it possible to use an image as the title of a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Is it possible to use an image as the title (text on the top) of the UINavigationBar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. UINavigationItem (not bar), has a titleView property.

In your view controller, set an imageView as that view controller's navigationItem's titleView.